# Test ads show on app but real ones dont show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

i am using unity and admob ,and now i have a problem 
When i try to show test ads they show without a problem , everything works fine, but when i try to show real ads they are not displayed.

I tried the following:
I created admob account
I coppied the AppID into my code , and also in the xml file 
I did everything from the turorials , with some changes because google dont know how to explain.Then i debugged with logcat , and i got the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
10-08 22:24:53.917 30153 30153 E AndroidRuntime: 
10-08 22:24:53.917 30153 30153 E AndroidRuntime: ******************************************************************************
10-08 22:24:53.917 30153 30153 E AndroidRuntime: * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here:                          *
10-08 22:24:53.917 30153 30153 E AndroidRuntime: * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
10-08 22:24:53.917 30153 30153 E AndroidRuntime: * to find your app ID.
```

This is my Code for showing banners

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdmobManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BannerView bannerView;
    void Start()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            string appId = "ca-app-pub-6068823890509836~9548685797";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string appId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511";
        #else
            string appId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Initialize the Google Mobile Ads SDK.
        MobileAds.Initialize(appId);

        this.RequestBanner();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void RequestBanner()
    {
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-6068823890509836/3679968367";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
            string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";
        #else
            string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();

        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

and this is my xml file

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest
> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="com.google.unity.ads" android:versionName="1.0"
> android:versionCode="1">   <application>
>     <uses-library android:required="false" android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" />
>     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
> android:value="ca-app-pub-6068823890509836~9548685797" />  
> </application> </manifest>
```

Also i made the banner yesterday so 24hours has passed .

Answer (score 0):

If test ads were already shown, I don't think there is anything wrong on your part.

> Once your app is making more requests, you should see more consistent results. Please note that test ads operate through the same channels as live ads. Being able to return a test ad ensures that your application is communicating properly with our network.

Source: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2993019?hl=en